# How to always show all breadcrumbs in nautilus?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

When I open a directory in nautilus using a shortcut, for example "Desktop", the top bar is of nautilus is showing: left arrow, Home, Desktop. When I press the arrow, I get to see links to root and "/home/".

How do I get it to never show the arrow, but instead always show all the parent directories?

I have seen tried `always_use_location_entry`, but it shows text instead of click-able links.

Comment: If possible you'd need to edit the source of nautilus, really not worth it to gain so little. (show Filesystem & home breadcrumbs by default when opening a Dir. in your Home instead of that tiny arrow

Comment: which version of nautilus are you using can you tell plese by going to help then about in nautilus

Comment: I'm on 3.4.2 too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, I don't think that is possible. The only interesting thing that you can do is use the <kbd>F3</kbd> to open another side file and <kbd>F9</kbd> to hide/show file tree.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the default behavior in 12.04, but it only applies once you are out of your home directory. (Sorry that that doesn't really help with 11.10.) So, if I start Nautilus in my home directory it shortens the path to be relative to my home directory. If I jump up one directory, it starts showing the full path. If I start Nautilus in any directory other than my home directory, it shows the full path.